# how to change css control font color using colorpicker

Tags: apache-flex

im using colorpicker for fontcolor. i want to know  when i choose any color from colorpicker, all text color shuld change to choosen color. is it possible to use css to over come the probelm .thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add an event handler to the change event of the colorpicker and assign the selectedColor property as the color style of the application.

```
application.setStyle("color", colorPicker.selectedColor);
```